# How to allow users to sign in to AWS Console from an android app

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I am not happy with the AWS Console app for Android that Amazon provides.  Specifically, I would like to view my CloudWatch logs from an app that isn't just a browser window.

I see that the AWS SDK for Android has support for getting CloudWatch log events, so I think I'll be able to handle that, but I'm not clear on how to set up a login page so that I can log in using IAM.

The idea is that I would create an IAM user and give it CloudWatchLogReadOnly access.  The Android AWS Console app for Android has such a login page and I would like to recreate that.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish what you are looking to do is to add user login to your app using a Cognito Identity Pool in conjunction with a SignInProvider. For SignInProviders you have multiple choices a) you can use Cognito User Pools to setup your own user store with the ability to sign-in/sign-up etc b) Or you can federate from a social login provider such as FaceBook, Google etc (See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in.html for more information)

As part of the setup of a Cognito Identity Pool and a SignProvider, two roles will be created for you - one for auth users ( for users who have signed in) and an unauth role (for users who haven't signed in). You can configure the CloudWatchLogReadOnly access on the auth role and that should get you properly setup.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Is there any way to ask for an AccountID/Alias + IAM username + Password to allow a log in to any arbitrary account?  I'm thinking if I have multiple people to distribute this to, and each of them has their own AWS account.

Comment: Using Cognito is a best practice as it gives you temporary credentials that are short lived and helps with keeping your app secure. Another option that I can think of, which is definitely not something that I recommend from a security standpoint, is to use the com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials that you can use to pass in the accessKey and secretKey of the IAM user into the app. As these keys are not short-lived, their usage in most circumstances is discouraged, but you can try it out to see if it fits what you are looking to do.